# traffic shaping with TC(CLASSFUL QDISCS,like prio,HTB,CBQ)not working after upgrade ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: linux, networking, traffic-shaping

all.I have a problem. I used tc with HTB to do traffic shaping on 14.04.like

```
tc qdisc add dev docker0 root handle 1: htb default 1024
```

This was work well on ubuntu 14.04 with docker 1.11. But after I upgrade ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04(not upgrade docker). When I execute same command:

```
tc qdisc add dev docker0 root handle 1: htb default 1024
```

All running containers cannot reach the network,even the default gateway.

```
/ # ip r l
default via 172.20.0.1 dev eth0 
172.20.0.0/16 dev eth0  src 172.20.0.2 
/ # ping 172.20.0.1
PING 172.20.0.1 (172.20.0.1): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 172.20.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

And i capture packet on host,like

```
tcpdump -vvv -nn -i docker0

tcpdump: listening on docker0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:44:59.611212 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.20.0.1 tell 172.20.0.2, length 28
15:45:00.629100 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.20.0.1 tell 172.20.0.2, length 28
15:45:01.653096 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.20.0.1 tell 172.20.0.2, length 28
```

And check the tc status of docker0:

```
    tc -s -d qdisc show dev docker0

qdisc htb 1: root refcnt 2 r2q 10 default 1024 direct_packets_stat 0 ver 3.17 direct_qlen 0
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 48, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

There something like,all package were lost. Can anyone give me some suggestion.Thanks

Comment: Are containers able to reach Internet before you create the root qdisc?  Also, could you please add the result of `ip link` before and after the command? And could you add `ip netns` result?